# ResNet, wrong data accessed when using decode_predictions in Google Colab

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, resnet

I have no idea what data is being accessed, it is not the images that are supposed to be accessed. The images that are supposed to be being accessed are from categories such as the Rotunda, RiceHall, ClarkHall, etc. (You'll see these categories as subfolders of a folder if you access the data by running the code.) These are accessed originally when the images are plotted, but then the information is not associated with them when decode_predictions is run. The result I am getting though is, in part:
n07930864 - cup          100.00%
n02317335 - starfish     0.00%
n02391049 - zebra        0.00%

Can someone please help me? I have no idea where cup, starfish, and zebra come from.

```
import sys
import sklearn
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial

%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42) 

# To plot pretty figures
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=14)
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "cnn"
IMAGES_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID)
os.makedirs(IMAGES_PATH, exist_ok=True)

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True, fig_extension="png", resolution=300):
    path = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, fig_id + "." + fig_extension)
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format=fig_extension, dpi=resolution) 

# Download dataset from Firebase
!wget https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uva-landmark-images.appspot.com/o/dataset.zip?alt=media&token=e1403951-30d6-42b8-ba4e-394af1a2ddb7 

# Extract content
!unzip "/content/dataset.zip?alt=media" 

from sklearn.datasets import load_files 
from keras.utils import np_utils

from keras.preprocessing import image
from tqdm import tqdm # progress bar

data_dir = "/content/dataset/"
batch_size = 32;
# IMPORTANT: Depends on what pre-trained model you choose, you will need to change these dimensions accordingly
img_height = 150; 
img_width = 150;

# Training Dataset
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "training",
    seed = 42,
    image_size= (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size
)

# Validation Dataset
validation_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "validation",
    seed = 42,
    image_size = (img_height, img_width),
    batch_size = batch_size
)        

type(train_ds) 

# Visualize some of the train samples of one batch
# Make sure you create the class names that match the order of their appearances in the "files" variable
class_names = ['AcademicalVillage', 'AldermanLibrary', 'AlumniHall', 'AquaticFitnessCenter', 
  'BavaroHall', 'BrooksHall', 'ClarkHall', 'MadisonHall', 'MinorHall', 'NewCabellHall', 
  'NewcombHall', 'OldCabellHall', 'OlssonHall', 'RiceHall', 'Rotunda', 'ScottStadium', 
  'ThorntonHall', 'UniversityChapel']

# Rows and columns are set to fit one training batch (32)
n_rows = 8
n_cols = 4
plt.figure(figsize=(n_cols * 3, n_rows * 3))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    for i in range (n_rows*n_cols):
        plt.subplot(n_rows, n_cols, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.title(class_names[labels[i]], fontsize=12)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.2, hspace=.2) 

from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout 
from keras import models 

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=14)
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)

def plot_image(image):
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")

def plot_color_image(image):
    plt.imshow(image, interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")  

base_model_50 = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet") 

images_resized = tf.image.resize(images, [224, 224]) 
plot_color_image(np.uint8(images_resized[0]))
plt.show() 

images_resized = tf.image.resize_with_pad(images, 224, 224, antialias=True)
plot_color_image(np.uint8(images_resized[0])) 

images_resized = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(images, 224, 224)
plot_color_image(np.uint8(images_resized[0]))
plt.show() 

inputs = keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input(images_resized * 255)
Y_proba = base_model_50.predict(inputs)  

top_K = keras.applications.resnet50.decode_predictions(Y_proba, top=3)
print(top_K[0])
print(top_K[1])
for image_index in range(len(images_resized)):
    for class_id, name, y_proba in top_K[image_index]:
        print("  {} - {:12s} {:.2f}%".format(class_id, name, y_proba * 100))
```

Comment: You could just get class name by creating a dictionary with class name and index and get result using numpy.  Check out this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55046/how-to-use-decode-predictions-for-non-imagenet-models).

Comment: @Nannigalaxy So I can see the class name and index when I run this code anyway, the issue is that the last 6 lines end up giving a result that I can't trace what source the result is even coming from. Particularly, there doesn't seem to be a folder containing the values that get returned